# Doctrine orm one to many with reference key also containing strings

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony

I have an entity called books and another one users.
Each book can have many authors(users).
So when I add a book I select the users that are registered on the site.
But if the author of the book doesn't have an account on the site I want to type his name by hand.

```
+----+---------+-----------+--+
| id | book_id | author_id |  |
 +----+---------+-----------+--+
|  1 |       1 | 1         |  |
|  2 |       1 | Mr.Paul   |  |
+----+---------+-----------+--+
```

See how the author_id is a string but also an reference key to an user?
Can I do this with doctrine or I will have to manage the inserts myself?

Edit:I have no idea what the right title should be
Edit2:A possible solution will be to make another table containing only authors that don't have an account on the website.

Comment: In my Optionon thats not a goot solution, i think it will be better if you do not just input a name, you should create a new author and then put this new author_id into the database table. 

Im not a Doctrine pro but i think thats not possible because its really bad practice

Comment: Or maybe create another table containing only authors that don't have an account on the website?

Comment: how  does your current author table look like ? 

I think you should have this tables `authors_books` , `books`, `authors` `~accounts` so then an author can have an account or not

Comment: I like this but in the authors table, I put my authors that don't have an account or I put both those who have an account and those who don't?

Comment: Both and in the authors table you have a column account_id and those who habe no accoun this row is empty

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking that you were talking about.This seems the best solutions.Making a one to many betwen account and authors.Could you post as an answer to mark it?I can't mark comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend following approach

You have a table `books` a table `accounts` and the following:

authors_books

```
+----+---------+-----------+--+
| id | book_id | author_id |  |
+----+---------+-----------+--+
|  1 |       1 | 1         |  |
|  2 |       1 | 2         |  |
+----+---------+-----------+--+
```

authors

```
 +----+---------+------------+--+
| id | name     | account_id |  |
+----+---------+------------+--+
|  1 | Mr. Paul | 1          |  |
|  2 | Simon    | (empty)    |  |
+----+---------+-------------+--+
```

the account_id can be empty